keyboard not load and Display
My whole project keyboard not visible but i click in bottom to enter text what is issue??
to check my images to see ?? check image

to check my videos to see ??text(see video)

I think keyboard not loading and project issue. first time keyboard not visible but after navigate keyboard show.

Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: minimal code.

I guess You should check the code of SceneDelegate If you load first ViewController at SceneDelegate instead of main.storyboard.
and Check If There are codes force the type of presentationStyle in whole project.

I use ios 12.3 version so we delete scene delegate file and set code in App Delegate ios swift
